# Why am i able to do this in the console window.window.window.window and it returns window ?

Tags: javascript

Why am i able to do this in the console `window.window.window.window` and append `.window` infinitely and it returns the DOM window ?

Comment: Just [because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.window).

Comment: Just imagine the fun if the window object had instead been called "buffalo".

Comment: It's called a circular reference. A property of an object refers to itself.

Comment: lol @Pointy, Stampede! `var buffalo = window; buffalo.buffalo = buffalo.window`

Comment: Also `buffalo.buffalo.buffalo.buffalo.buffalo` which is a cool grammatically-correct English sentence. (Think of a newspaper headline about large woolly bovines from upstate New York who are rude to neighbors of their ilk.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the window object points to the window object itself.

Some reasons for this behaviour include

- makes it easier to refer to the global object (otherwise you'd have
  to do a manual var window = this; assignment at the top of your
  script).
- Without this property you wouldn't be able to write for example  "window.open('http://google.com/')" you'd have to just use "open('http://google.com/')" instead
- Another reason to use this property is for libraries which wish to offer OOP-versions and non-OOP versions (especially JavaScript modules).

Further reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.window)

Answer (score 5):

Because the `window` object has a `window` property that points to itself.

It is the same as if you wrote:

```
var foo = {};
foo.foo = foo;
console.log(foo.foo.foo.foo.foo.foo.foo);
```

For fun the `window` object also has a [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self) property that points to itself and (if you're not in a frameset) a [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) property that also points to it. Thus you can write:

```
console.log(window.window.top.self.top.self.window.window.self.top.top.self);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the `window` object has a property called `window` that contains a reference to the `window` object.

It works on the same principle as this:

```
var foo = {}; 
foo.foo = foo; 
foo.bar = 1; 
alert(foo.foo.foo.foo.foo.bar);
```

Comment: LOL at our parallel initial answers and then edits. Gotta +1 you for that. :)

Answer (score 2):

`window` is a reference to the global object, and the `window` variable is in the global scope, hence it's essentially a pointer to itself.